# Is There any way to setup background service which still run even apps (android/ios) is closed without firebase

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am trying to make Apps using flutter. This app should has capable to receive notification even apps is closed, maybe anyone has made something similiar and want to share how you do it please.

For now I have try flutter_background_service and flutter_local_notidicaiton for displaying the notifications.

Comment: Implementing reliable mobile notifications without FCM/APN isn't really a feasible thing - your background service simply won't be run as consistently as system services. On iOS this is pretty well documented, on Android see [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com/).

Comment: Yea, look so pain to setup our own service without using FCM. Or is it possible that we still using FM sdk but the listener will listen our service not FCM broadcast ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible.